# svn diff on a revision merged from another branch

Tags: svn

I had a branch, project-branch, that I finished with and merged back into trunk.

Now I'm working in trunk again and I'd like to see changes for a revision that I made on project-branch.  I can use -g to see these revisions in the log, but when i do diff -c on the revision in question, it comes up empty.  Is there a way to see the diff of this revision from trunk?  Or do I have to specifically run the diff on project-branch?

EDIT:
Okay I can diff -c on the revision in which I actually merged project-branch into trunk.  But that has way more stuff in it than I am interested in viewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke the following command in the working copy. `^/` is a short-cut for the root of the current repository, so that the diff will not be truncated to the current working directory.

```
svn diff -c 42 ^/
```